# Ones and Zeroes

Tags: riddle, number-sequence

Underneath this is a series of ones and zeroes; they are not to be interpreted as binary numbers. Perhaps some research is in order to determine their meaning. Comb the web once you determine what they are and you'll find resources that will help you determine what they represent. And if you're wondering, would the 'trivia' tag be relevant here, the answer is no because you already have a hint hidden herein.

> 000000000 101 0110111 0110111 0110111 0100011 0101111 0010011 01010 1110010 1000010 1110100 1001110 1001000 1100110 101 000000000

Comment: How did I get a +1 when this showed only having 1 view?! My mind is blown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in progress, [EAN-13 Barcode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10162/Creating-EAN-Barcodes-with-C) also [here](http://www.austincc.edu/hannigan/Math1513/codes.html)

So on the digits, the breakdown I have so far,

```
Quiet Zone  000000000
Lead / Trailer  101

Manufacturer's Number

0110111 0110111 0110111 0100011 0101111 0010011
  8        8       8       4       6      2    


Separator   01010
              5  


Product Number

1110010 1000010 1110100 1001110 1001000 1100110 
   0       3       9       5       8       1   


Lead / Trailer  101
Quiet Zone  000000000
```

888462 039581

[image: Barcode Example]

Was identifying what the code is the answer or are you looking for a particular message contained therein ?

```
UPC-A       888462039581
EAN/UCC-13      0888462039581
Description     iPhone 6 Plus Gold 16GB
Issuing Country     United States
Last Modified       29 Mar 2015, 5:21 PM
Pending Requests        0
```

Comment: To answer your question, 'Comb the web once you determine what they are and you'll find resources that will help you determine what they represent' was my attempt at indicating that the answer is the thing being pointed to, sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: Ah as I posted this it seems you updated with the product. Well done figuring it out and finding the answer! First sword inscriptions and now barcodes.

Comment: @NeedAName , thanks, now if i had a functional math brain I'd be happy, but on that I am as dumb as a bag ful of bags. xD

Comment: @moonbutt74 +1 for bag full of bags